# Can I achieve this with linq instead of For Each?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
 Dim customers As List(Of Customer) = New List(Of Customer)
    For Each mbi In fordContracts
        customers.Add(mbi.Customer)
    Next
```

Is it possible to query fordContracts for customers? It is an IList(of mbi) and each mbi object has an EntityRef to a Customer object. I just wanted to know if there was a better way to achieve this using Linq.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adding to an existing list (which may have some elements already):

```
customers.AddRange(From mbi In fordContracts Select mbi.Customer)
```

If you want to get a brand new list:

```
customers = (From mbi In fordContracts Select mbi.Customer).ToList()
```